# Как избавиться от слэшей url

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, веб-программирование

Как избавиться от слэшей в url?

site.com/ddsda//////// адресовать на site.com/ddsda/

Содержимое htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [f,l]
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets)/$ - [L]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо добавить в файл **.htaccess** следующую строку:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*?)//+(.*)$ $1/$2 [E=REDIR:1,N]
```

[Подобная тема обсуждалась здесь...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170246/multiple-slashes-on-url-how-to-remove)